# Twilio not working - after connecting with Database [on pythonanywhere]

Tags: python, mysql, twilio

Hi I want to create a chatbot to gather user's information and store user inputs in MySQL database. I followed this [tutorial](https://chatbotslife.com/build-a-working-sms-chat-bot-in-10-minutes-b8278d80cc7a) and everything worked but after implementing database connection, I couldn't access it via Twilio SMS. I can still check the chatbot flow from dialogflow but twilio is not responding. Here is the code.. it was big so couldn't share the whole webhook function. Please tell me how to connect with database.. seems like dialogflow inbuilt chatbot is working fine but my main motive is to work from Twilio SMS. How to establish that?
P.s. before database connection, it was working fine just like in the tutorial.

```
import json
import apiai
import os
from flask import Flask
from twilio.rest import Client
from twilio.http.http_client import TwilioHttpClient

from flask import request, make_response, jsonify



# Twilio account info
account_sid = "_####__"
auth_token = "_###__"
account_num = "+_###__"

proxy_client = TwilioHttpClient()
proxy_client.session.proxies = {'https': os.environ['https_proxy']}

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token, http_client=proxy_client)

# api.ai account info
CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN = "_###__"
ai = apiai.ApiAI(CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN)

app = Flask(__name__)


# ---database handling starts-----
# create a MySQL client connecting to your MySQL server
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="---###---",
  user="---###---",
  passwd="---###---",
  database="---###---"
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()


# ----webhook method calling----
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    global counting_id
    req = request.get_json(silent=True, force=True)
    action = req.get('queryResult').get('action')

    # WEBHOOK CODE

    # return make_response(jsonify({"speech": res}))




@app.route('/hello')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello api.ai (from Flask!)'

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def server():
    from flask import request

    # get SMS metadata
    msg_from = request.values.get("From", None)
    msg = request.values.get("Body", None)
    # print(msg)
    # print('msg_from=', msg_from)

    # prepare API.ai request
    req = ai.text_request()
    req.lang = 'en'  # optional, default value equal 'en'
    req.query = msg
    # req.session_id = msg_from

    # print(ai)
    # print(req)

    # get response from API.ai
    api_response = req.getresponse()
    responsestr = api_response.read().decode('utf-8')
    response_obj = json.loads(responsestr)
    reply="Hello [reply from flask]"
    if 'result' in response_obj:
        response = response_obj["result"]["fulfillment"]["speech"]
        # send SMS response back via twilio
        reply=client.messages.create(to=msg_from, from_= account_num, body=response)

    return str(reply)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Do you see anything in your logs? (there are links to logs on PythonAnywhere "Web" configuration page)

Comment: I am not sure what to look for in those logs. Like I am not getting any error.. just not able to connect Twilio. and not even able to send the response back. This file is running without any errors tho.

Comment: Log what you're getting back from Twilio and putting into `response_obj` (Prints to stderr will appear in your error log) My guess is that `response_obj` does not have a result key and so you're just skipping the section of code that creates the message.

Comment: Okay. How can I connect with that? if i may ask. I am new to Flask so not able to figure out the correct way to send the response back to twilio.

Comment: Inspect the response_obj that you do get back from Twilio so that you know what you're dealing with. Perhaps it's an error message, or a different type of response to the one you expect.